# Are periodic work requests supposed to execute immediately?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

## EDIT (TL;DR)

I didn't realize there was more than one constructor for periodic work requests. The clue to my confusion was in the comments of the accepted answer.

## Background

I have a few special cases I am trying to solve for while scheduling work. One of them involves doing work immediately and then creating a periodic work request. I found this in the Android's **PeriodicWorkRequest** [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest):

> This work executes multiple times until it is cancelled, with the first execution happening immediately or as soon as the given Constraints are met.

I figured that this meant work would execute upon creating a request. However, this was not what happened in my test implementation. (For this work there is no need for a CoroutineWorker or network connection constraints but its applicable to my business need so I am testing it)

**Starting Worker**

```
object WorkerManager {
    private val TAG = "WORKER_MANAGER_TEST"

    fun buildWorkRequest(
        startingNumber: Int,
        context: Context
    ) {
        val constraints =
            Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build()

        val workRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
            PeriodicWorker::class.java,
            1,
            TimeUnit.HOURS,
            15,
            TimeUnit.MINUTES
        )
            .setInputData(
                workDataOf(Constants.INPUT_DATA_NUMBER to startingNumber)
            )
            .addTag(Constants.PERIODIC_WORKER_TAG)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            Constants.PERIODIC_WORKER_NAME,
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
            workRequest
        )

        Log.d(TAG, "Worker started. Starting number: $startingNumber")
    }
}
```

**Worker**:

```
class PeriodicWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters): CoroutineWorker(context,
    workerParams
) {
    companion object {
        var isInit = false
        var count: Int = 1
    }

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = try {
        if (!isInit) {
            count = inputData.getInt(Constants.INPUT_DATA_NUMBER, Constants.DEFAULT_DATA_NUMBER)
            isInit = true
        } else {
            count += 1
        }

        Repository.updateNumber(count)

        Result.success()
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        Result.failure()
    }
}
```

**Repo**:

```
object Repository {
    private val TAG = "REPOSITORY_TAG"
    private val _number = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val number: StateFlow<Int> = _number

    suspend fun updateNumber(number: Int) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Number updated to: $number")
        _number.emit(number)
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**:

```
class NumberViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _count = MutableLiveData(0)
    val count: LiveData<Int> = _count

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            Repository.number.collect {
                _count.postValue(it)
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

### Results

I started a worker with 10 as the starting number.

Logs:

```
8:45am  - Worker started. Starting number: 10
9:37am  - Number updated to: 10                 // work executed
10:37am - Number updated to: 11                 // work executed
11:37am - Number updated to: 12                 // work executed
```

#### Device Info

OS Version 28 -- Samsung SM-T390

## My Conclusion

**Constraints** -
Cannot be an issue. I had network connection during the above test and that is the only given constraint.

**Battery Optimizations** -
I am sure that this app was white listed prior to running this test.

So in conclusion it seems that *PeriodicWorkRequests* **DO NOT** perform immediate work. The Android documentation should instead say:

> This work executes multiple times until it is cancelled, with the first period beginning immediately. The first work execution then happens within the first flex interval given the constraints are met.

## Question

Does my conclusion seem reasonable? Is there something I haven't considered?

Comment: It's interesting that the first time `updateNumber` is called at 9:37am, the value of `number` is 11, so `count` had already been incremented. That should mean the `else` branch was taken, so the worker should have already been executed once before. I don't get why it didn't appear in the logs.

Comment: I am so sorry. I manually wrote these logs and they are false. Thanks for that! I updated them to the way they actually appeared.

Comment: the answer is in your request constructor

Comment: What you mean to say, @Alex Rmcf, is: the repeatInterval declared in your request constructor is also considered a constraint that must be satisfied prior to the initial execution.

Comment: English is not my best skill)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand this constructor:

```
          PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(Class<? extends ListenableWorker> workerClass, 
    long repeatInterval, TimeUnit repeatIntervalTimeUnit,
 long flexInterval, TimeUnit flexIntervalTimeUnit)
```

means that your work will be executed inside `flexInterval` of `repeatInterval`

Comment: This is the case with any periodicWorkRequest. I am just confused by the wording in the documentation.

Comment: Actually this is not the case with ANY periodicWorkRequest. If you use this constructor - PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(Class<? extends ListenableWorker> workerClass, 
    long repeatInterval, TimeUnit repeatIntervalTimeUnit) your periodic work request will execute immediately after you call this - WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            Constants.PERIODIC_WORKER_NAME,
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
            workRequest
        )

Comment: Ah, I didn't even realize you could make a periodic work request without a flex interval. I will test this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are overthinking it. Please dump the JS:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/debugging

Use **adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler**

And just check what are the Unsatisfied constraints in the dump:

```
  Required constraints: TIMING_DELAY CONNECTIVITY [0x90000000]
  Satisfied constraints: DEVICE_NOT_DOZING BACKGROUND_NOT_RESTRICTED WITHIN_QUOTA [0x3400000]
  Unsatisfied constraints: TIMING_DELAY CONNECTIVITY [0x90000000]
```

Also:

```
Minimum latency: +1h29m59s687ms
```

Comment: `Minimum latency: +45m0s0ms
....
Required constraints: TIMING_DELAY CONNECTIVITY [0x90000000]
Satisfied constraints: DEVICE_NOT_DOZING [0x2400000]
Unsatisfied constraints: TIMING_DELAY [0x80000000]`

So then one of the constraints of the PeriodicWorkRequest is the delay has been elapsed.

Comment: You need at least 45min to pass. Compared to the Enqueue time. Besides that, if I remember correctly, timing delay is not only if you put a delay, but also if the work is set to retry depending on the backoff policy.

Answer (score 1):

By default, periodic work requests run immediately. You can change this in your builder by using

`.setInitialDelay(Duration)`.

If you look at the code for the builder, you can see that the default `initialDelay` value is `0`